# Google+ Picasa photo upload - low resolution

Tags: google-plus-photos

I tried uploading an album to Google+ via Picasa.

I tried selecting both *Original Size Images* as well as *2048 Max width* options. (Photos are 8MP and I have not run out of free storage.)

But the photos are uploaded in 800x600.

What could be the reason behind this?

Picasa shows two blue rounded arrows next to each photo.

Does it mean that it has only uploaded thumbnails/previews and not the entire photos?

Comment: When you open your image in Picasa's photo preview what do you see on the right sidebar? There might be the details about your photo.

Comment: Can you share a screen shot? Have you tried with a newer version of Picasa?

Answer (score -1):

If you use the picasa client and are signed up to google+ it shouldn't be a problem.

http://support.google.com/picasa/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=106867

Comment: I have that already..
but still photos on Google+ are in 800x600..
and i have already visited that link.